# How do I get a handle to a popup window in gwt?

Tags: javascript, gwt

Hi can someone tell me how to do something like the following in gwt?

```
test(){
  var win =
    window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                "mywindow",
                "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
  win.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, trying again.

Off the top of my head, use a PopupPanel or some subclass of that Widget.  Then you have a "handle" to it.  Insert a Frame widget in the panel and set the URL of the Frame to the external site you want.  Handle the sizing and other aspects using the methods provided by the PopupPanel class.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get and manipulate `window` handles by creating an [overlay type](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html):

```
public class MyWindow extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected MyWindow() {
  }

  public static native MyWindow open(String url, String name) /*-{
    return $wnd.open(url, name);
  }-*/;

  public static native MyWindow open(String url, String name, String options) /*-{
    return $wnd.open(url, name, options);
  }-*/;

  public native void setHref(String href) /*-{
    if (this.location) {
      this.location.href = href;
    }
  }-*/;
}
```

Note that once the window origin changes you will no longer be able to manipulate the window.